# using for loop in repeating number of day

Tags: java, for-loop

How to repeat day in number when user input  any number like: 12, then the output is like this

Input any number: 13

Day: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5

using for loop?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++)
{

      System.out.print(" " +(i%7)+1);
}
```

Assuming it is java code that you are talking about.

Comment: print(" " +((i%7)+1))

Comment: O yea. Thanks Martin!